# How do I stop a terminal from closing?

Tags: python

I'm looking to create a python script that doesn't close.

I'm wondering how people do these sort of things with malicious software.
It's not something I want to replicate, but now that I've pondered about it I want to learn how people stop users from closing a program.
No, I'm not using this for malicious software, I'm just curious.
I want to learn how to make a terminal window almost impossible to close. Maybe it creates a new window when the first one is closed, or something along those lines.

I can't find any resources on this besides a few things involving TKInter, I'm hoping to find a way to do this without TKInter though, do you have any ideas? Could you help me out?

Comment: _For no reason in particular, I want to learn how to make a terminal window almost impossible to close._  .... 

Comment: Well I wondered how people do it, isn't this a place to learn?

Comment: A terminal as in interactive python? Or your shell (which is nothing to do with Python)?

Comment: What has python to do with this ?

Comment: It's the language I'm trying to do this in, aghh... I'm new to the site, one second...

Comment: Now you're saying you want a script that doesn't stop? `while True: pass`

Comment: Show what you've tried, and then people may be able to figure out exactly what you're trying to do and thus be able to help you. Don't, and they won't.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really python specific but you have complete control over what happens when the "X" is clicked on forms (at least in Windows applications). The default behaviour is simply to close the window (and end the application if it is the main form). All you need to do is override this behaviour and the window won't close. This obviously does not stop the process being ended manually (via task manager etc.).

That being said, you won't be able to do this with "the terminal" (I'm assuming you're refering to IDLE, the command prompt in windows, or terminal in Linux?) as it isn't actually part of your python script, it just runs it. If you want to do this in python, you'll need python to actually render a GUI and then change it's behaviour to do what you want:

https://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming

**Edit:**

Assuming this is purely educational... this should do what you want using a window created by Tkinter:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def doNothing():
    pass

root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', doNothing)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way to do it is just leave one input statement at the end of your code, like this:

```
input()
```